# Add first link from post in custom field - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I m trying to add the first link from the post content to a custom field. Something is wrong and I ve been trying to get it to work but no luck. What should I do to add the link to "link" custom field?

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'check_post' );
function check_post( $post_id ) {
$user_info = get_userdata(1);

    function get_first_link() {

        global $post, $posts;
        preg_match_all('/href\s*=\s*[\"\']([^\"\']+)/', $post->post_content, $links);
        return $links[1][0];

    }
    $first_link = get_first_link();

    add_post_meta($post_id, 'link', $first_link, true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'users', $user_info->user_login, true);
}
```

EDIT
I got it working halfway. It saves the url, but it doesn't save it when the post is published. It saves it on update. What do I need to use? I tried using publish_post but that saved the url on update also.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 2 );
function my_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

$matches = array();
preg_match_all( '/href\s*=\s*[\"\']([^\"\']+)/', $post->post_content, $matches );

$first_link = false;
if ( ! empty( $matches[1][0] ) )
    $first_link = $matches[1][0];

$user_info = get_userdata(1);

$meta_link = $_POST['link'];

$args = array(
  'post__not_in'=> array($id),
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => array('publish'),
  'meta_query' => array(

      array(
    'key' => 'link',
    'value' => $first_link,
    'compare' => '='
      )       
  )
);
$existingMeta = get_posts( $args );

if(empty($existingMeta)){
    //Go ahead and save meta data
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link', esc_url_raw( $first_link ) );
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'users', $user_info->user_login);
}else{
    //Revert post back to draft status
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link', $existingMeta[0]->ID );
        update_post_meta($existingMeta[0]->ID, 'users', $user_info->user_login);

    //Now perform checks to validate your data. 
       //Note custom fields (different from data in custom metaboxes!) 
       //will already have been saved.
        $prevent_publish= true;//Set to true if data was invalid.
        if ($prevent_publish) {
        // unhook this function to prevent indefinite loop
        remove_action('save_post', 'my_save_post');

        // update the post to change post status
        wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));

        }

}
}
```

Comment: you could try it on the `'save_post'` hook instead?

Comment: If I try with `save_post`, I get a Fatal Error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_first_link() (previously declared in /home/ddnets/public_html/site.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php:618) in /home/ddnets/public_html/site.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 616`

Comment: Declare get_first_link outside of check_post, because save_post runs twice (or more). You should also check for revisions, before adding your post meta. Also, you should use update_post_meta, since add_post_meta will fail if keys already exist. Here's more about the save_post hook: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: I tried declaring get_first_link just before add_action, but still nothing. See my edit. not sure if I did this right. @kovshenin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 2 );
function my_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all( '/href\s*=\s*[\"\']([^\"\']+)/', $post->post_content, $matches );

    $first_link = false;
    if ( ! empty( $matches[1][0] ) )
        $first_link = $matches[1][0];

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link', esc_url_raw( $first_link ) );
}
```

Comment: Nice. My goal is to check if the $first_link already exists, and if it does, add this to the its post: `update_post_meta($post_id, 'users', $user_info->user_login);` and delete or not publish the new post. Am I on the right path?

Comment: You can get the existing value with `get_option` and compare and then do whatever you have to do. However, note that the `save_post` hook is fired after the post has been saved. It can also mean the post has already been published, so you might want to unpublish it. If you decide to do that, make sure you remove your `my_save_post` action before firing `wp_update_post` otherwise you'll end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: one more thing. What can I do if I am posting via xmlrpc? @kovshenin

Comment: @ciprian your save_post hook will fire, even if you're posting from xmlrpc.

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with ifttt.com. I use it, and I think it uses xmlrpc. But it doesn't save the url in the custom field when adding a post. I added the function in the edit above. @kovshenin